# Oracle global temp table - can't find the inserted records

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am trying to insert some records into an oracle global temp table using the Spring  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

```
try{
          final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
          final MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource(); 
          params.addValue("id", 1);   
          params.addValue("value", 1);
          sqlSub = "INSERT INTO MY_GLOBAL_TEMP (id, value) VALUES (:id, :value)" ;
          namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sqlSub, params);
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}




String sql = "select count(*) from MY_GLOBAL_TEMP"; 
      int count =  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
               sql, Integer.class);
      System.out.println(count);
```

Record insert query executed without any errors. But the count is getting 0. I cant see the records in the table also.

Created the table by,

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_GLOBAL_TEMP (ID NUMBER,VALUE NUMBER)  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: Where do you commit the transaction?

Comment: Do we need to commit this explicitly?

Comment: probably you have autocommit in java. So when you execute statements one by one, first already commited. And commit for temp table = truncate data. [this could help](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/tips2.htm). Maybe you also need to find how to execute it in one session if you have multisession now

Comment: But the temp table is created as `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` right?

Comment: What is jdbcTemplate? Can you guarantee it is using same connection not pool or new connection?

Comment: Try to create this table as common heap table and check again. You might  not be able to see data in your temporary table if Java closes session after inserting or uses another session for select.